# Difference betweeen FirstOrDefault() and FirstOrDefault<string>() in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

What's the difference between `FirstOrDefault() and FirstOrDefault<string>()` in LINQ ?

Could somebody give me some simple explanation?

```
TypedDataSet ds= codeComponent.GetAllCode("test");
string status = (from s in ds.Codes
                 where s.Name == "hello"
                 select s.Remarks).FirstOrDefault();


TypedDataSet ds= codeComponent.GetAllCode("test");
string status = (from s in ds.Codes
                 where s.Name == "hello"
                 select s.Remarks).FirstOrDefault<string>();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No semantic difference; the compiler is able to infer the generic argument from the type of the collection.  Just syntactic sugar that makes our lives a little bit simpler.

Note that this is not specific to LINQ; the spec defines when generic arguments may be inferred as well as when they cannot.

Comment: I like that we posted practically the same answer :)

Comment: @DBM: Yeah... I like the simple ones :D

Answer (score 4):

There is no difference. When you leave off the explicit `<string>`, the compiler is able to infer the type.

Answer (score 2):

C# 3.0 has Automatic Generic Inference, if the types are not ambiguous, explicit type is not required.
Look at definition of FirstOrDefault(), which is an extension method (also C# 3.0)

```
public static TSource FirstOrDefault<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source);
```

In your case, assume Remarks field/property is type of string, TSource can be inferred as string.